# Storing values to be retrieved by user

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that allows the user to input and view passwords that are encrypted when inputted and decrypted when accessed by the user. I figured that this could be done using a text document, however I'm unsure of how to get my code to interact with said document. Any ideas on how to do this/alternative ways that I can accomplish my task?

Comment: Show us your code and how far do you get it

Comment: Are you asking how to do File I/O?

Comment: Do you want to know how Java reads a file from the file system? It is not clear from your question. Can you please elaborate on the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could save your input in a text file with BufferedWriter and read the document with BufferedReader.
An example would be:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
out.write(password)
out.close


BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
 System.out.println(line);
}
in.close
```